# What is the number of ways to distribute m indistinguishable balls to n distinguishable boxes (with extra givens)?

Tags: combinatorics

> What is the number of ways to distribute $m$ indistinguishable balls to $n$ distinguishable boxes given no box can be empty and every ball has to be in a box?

This was a programming question that I found, but I'm curious how to do this in a combinatorics method.

Comment: This is a classic for the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) method

Comment: You want to find the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n = m$ in the positive integers.  The method for solving this problem is explained in Theorem 1 in the link eeperly16 provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using stars and bars. Since you don't want to allow empty boxes, first place one of the balls into each box. Now you have $m-n$ balls. This becomes a regular stars and bars problem, where you can partition the remaining balls, allowing empty boxes. This gives a total of ${{m-1}\choose{n-1}}$ combinations.